# Music- what if I move or cancel distribution service

Tags: copyright, united-kingdom, music

Suppose a songwriter wants to use a distribution service to push songs  to spotify. From reviews on YouTube all of the distributors (ditto, distro kid, ccd babe etc.) they all have their influencers who don't like them.

Lets say the artist publishes with ditto but then wants to move to distro kid, what happens to the music? are they obliged to move it to the other distributor of the artist's choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will depend on the exact provisions of the contract between the artist and a distribution service. The contract might specify that works once submitted are to be under that service for a specified tiem, or even permanently. Or it might specify that representation ends when the contract expires or is terminated.

Comment: Thanks for answer! Take ditto. they say ".. For all User Submissions, you hereby grant Ditto a license to translate, modify (..) and reproduce .."; also "You agree that the licenses you grant are royalty-free, perpetual, sublicenseable, irrevocable, and worldwide, provided that when you delete your Ditto account, your Public User Submissions may remain fully available and you understand and agree that it may not be possible to delete certain other content from Ditto’s records, and that your User Submissions may remain viewable elsewhere"

Comment: But then they say "This is a license only – your ownership in User Submissions is not affected. What does it mean then? can i move to distrokid and keep my files in spotify? will i end up with two songs on spotify - one through ditto and one through distro kid?